# How to italicize and underline a particular part of circular text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I have drawn two concentric circles and divided them into three sectors containing some text. How do I decorate the text?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}   
    \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (10cm); %outer circle

    \foreach \i/\j in {0/text-1, 120/text-2, 240/text-3}
    {
        \draw [black] (0,0) -- (\i:10cm);
        \draw [black] (0,0) -- (\i+1:10cm);

        \path 
        [
        decorate, 
        decoration={
            text along path, 
            reverse path, 
            text={\j}, 
            text align=center
        }
        ] (\i:10mm) arc (\i:{\i+120}:10mm);
    }

    \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (5cm); %inner most circle

    \foreach \k/\m in {0/Text in Italics: Some text here., 120/Text to be underlined: Some text here too., 240/Text to be underlined and then italicized: Some more text here.} 
    {           
        \path 
        [
        decorate, 
        decoration={
            text along path, 
            reverse path, 
            text={\m}, 
            text align=center
        }
        ] (\k:65mm) arc (\k:{\k+120}:65mm);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the italics, which is easy:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (10cm); %outer circle

  \foreach \i/\j in {0/text-1, 120/text-2, 240/text-3}
  {
      \draw [black] (0,0) -- (\i:10cm);
      \draw [black] (0,0) -- (\i+1:10cm);

      \path
      [
      decorate,
      decoration={
          text along path,
          reverse path,
          text={\j},
          text align=center
      }
      ] (\i:10mm) arc (\i:{\i+120}:10mm);
  }

  \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (5cm); %inner most circle

  \foreach \k/\m in {0/|\itshape|Text in Italics||: Some text here., 120/Text to be underlined: Some text here too., 240/Text to be underlined and |\itshape|then italicized||: Some more text here.}
  {
      \path
      [
      decorate,
      decoration={
          text along path,
          reverse path,
          text={\m},
          text align=center
      }
      ] (\k:65mm) arc (\k:{\k+120}:65mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: italics]

For underlining, you have to make choices.

1. Pick some other effect rather than underlining and proceed as above. Straightforward and typographically preferable, too boot. That is, it is easy and aesthetically better. It doesn't meet your desiderata, but you shouldn't *want* to underline text, so it meets the desiderata you ought to have. Sadly, this may not be much help.
2. Figure out the relevant points and draw the arcs manually. Straightforward but fiddly. Tricky maintenance. Inelegant. Meets desiderata.
3. Switch to `text effects along path`, which allows you to handle every character in the sequence as an independent node. More powerful, but very slow. If you need to do this a lot in a document, it makes a significant difference to compilation times. On the other hand, PGF/Ti*k*Z is already very slow, so compilation time is probably not a major concern.

Of these, option 1 would be my recommended and preferred option. Failing that, option 3.

Comment: If there was ever a place for upright italics, it is here. IMNSHO, upright italics would look significantly better than the italics shown above. I would substitute them if I really wanted italics here. Colour would be my first choice for distinguishing the different parts of the text, though I realise that is not unproblematic, either.

Comment: where I can find upright italic font? :-)

Comment: Thank you @cfr, I went ahead with using different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something lighter, based on @cfr solution: the `foreach` can be replaced by something like this:

```
\path
[
decorate,
decoration={text along path,
            raise=.7ex,
            text align={align=left},
            text={Some |\bfseries|Bold|| and \itshape|italics|| text}
           }
] (0:65mm) arc (0:120:65mm);
```